# In a byte, how to swap the 4 higher bits with its 4 lower bits

Tags: c, byte

I had an interview yesterday.

One of the question i've been asked was:
how can one replace the 4 higher bits of a byte with its 4 lower bits.
We're talking on native C here, btw.

For example, consider the following byte:
AB
The output should be:
BA

Well, the guy there told me it can be done within a single command.
I've only managed to do it in 3 commands.

I asked him for the answer, but he was reluctant.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the optimized assembly output of your three commands? Maybe you can deduce what to do from that.

Comment: you could use asm's ROL, but there isn't one in C.

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for a single operation in C (two operands, one operator) that would convert 0xab to 0xba (and any other input in the same way)? The only "single command" I can think of is a look-up table, but I think we need some clarifications.

Comment: actually i'm not sure why i did that. i'll remove it.

Comment: First you say that you have to *replace* upper bits with lower bits, but then you give an example of *swapping* upper bits with lower bits. So, what is it supposed to be: replace or swap?

Comment: It's just my poor English. i meant swap

Answer (score 10):

```
uint8_t b = 0xab;

b = (b << 4) | (b >> 4);
```

`b` now equals 0xba.

Is that what you meant?

Comment: Hi,
Thank u for the quick answer.
That was exactly my answer.
i was just editing my question to clarify that the answer should be only **one** command.

Comment: If you were writing in ASM you could do it in one instruction on most processors. There is usually a "rol" op code.

Comment: What's a "command", here? Omri's answer doesn't use any "commands", just operators, one variable, and a couple of literals.

Comment: I'm calling it impossible to do it in standard C with a single operation and a single operator, since C has no single operator which can do that.

Comment: He insisted it's possible. but he was kindda strange man :)
anyhow, that's what i thought.
Thank u

Comment: One command? If you measure "command" by the amount of semicolons, you can build a 3d computer game using only one command: http://www.ioccc.org/2005/anon/

Answer (score 8):

I think this might be the answer your interviewer was looking for:

```
unsigned char a = 0xab;
a *= 16.0625;
```

It's short and pretty, but it won't be too efficient when compiled.

Comment: +1 wow! just a note: `0.0625` is 1/16 ... so just multiply the number by 16 (and ignore overflows), divide the number by 16 (ignore underflows) and sum the values!

Comment: That's really a very creative solution. :)

Comment: I know this is old but would you mind please expounding a bit (no pun intended) on why you said "it won't be too efficient when compiled"?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff It will do floating point calculations, and conversions from char to double and back. That's unlikely to be fast compared to a byte rotate instruction.

Comment: @PaulHankin, that makes a lot of sense, thank you for replying I really appreciate.

Answer (score 6):

In gcc on x86, you can use `ror` as a single inline assembler operation;

```
unsigned char a = 0x45;

asm("ror $4,%1" : "+r" (a));

printf("0x%x\n", a);
```

Outputs `0x54`.

As an alternative, as suggested by OmriBarel in the comments, if you can do some preparations, a lookup will work also;

```
uint8_t* lookup = malloc(256);
unsigned int i;
for(i=0; i<256; i++) lookup[i]= i>>4 | i<<4;

uint8_t a = 0x54;
a = lookup[a];
printf("0x%x\n", a);
```

Outputs `0x45`.

Comment: @Sayakiss Could you show the exact program? I get 0x54 in codeblocks too with this code pasted into an otherwise empty main (and the appropriate includes for printf)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson #include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 0x45;
    asm("ror $4,%1" : "=r" (a) : "r" (a));
    printf("0x%x\n", a);
}

Comment: @Sayakiss Exactly the same program on 10.05 with mingw gcc as a compiler gives 0x54 for me. Try the somewhat simplified version I added above, you can use `+r` instead of `=r`&`r`.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not really meaningfully worded. What's "one command"? What's "command"?

One can do that by using a translation table, for example. The actual swap will look like `b = table[b]`, assuming the table was initialized in advance. Is that one "command" or not? Does the assignment operator count as a separate "command" in addition to `[]` operator?

Comment: I like the look-up table idea.  But it seems this one would be rather inefficient, repeating every 16 entries, but requiring 256 entries.  Unless we do `table[b%16]`.

Comment: You could just make a function call or define a macro, they're both single "commands" too.

Comment: @John: I'm not sure what you mean. It appears that the OP talks about *swapping* the bits (even though he uses the word "replace"). If so, the table will not repeat and all 256 entries will be necessary.

Comment: @AndreyT Sorry, I was still not worrying about the bottom bits.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I'm just catching on a technicality here, but the instruction you've given us is not to swap the two nibbles, but just replace the higher one with the lower one.  In my mind that would convert 0xAB into 0xBB, not necessarily 0xBA.

```
b = (b << 4) | (b & 0xf);
```

does that.  If you're not worried about what happens to the lower bits, then I would just

```
b <<= 4;
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about that, but then the example is clearly misleading.

Comment: But we don't know if that was the interviewers example or the OP's example demonstrating his interpretation of the question.

Comment: I should have written swap instead of replace. i'm sorry.